# Understanding anonymous functions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand a function, and how it works. However, I am unsure of the following:

```
 function(msg) { alert(msg); }
```

If this is not assigned to anything, how is it called?

I am more familiar with this:

```
function alert(msg) { // set it
   alert(msg);
}

alert('hello!'); //call it
```

Comment: that first snippet, as-is, causes a syntax error. I think you've left something important off.

Comment: Ah, I just copied it from a tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are four common ways to call an anonymous function:

save it to a variable like so:

```
var fn = function(msg) {
   // do something
}
```

execute by wrapping in parenthesis like so:

```
 (function(msg) {
    console.log( msg ); // -> 'This is my message'
 })('This is my message');
```

execute by prepending with an "!"

```
 !function(msg) {
    console.log( msg ); // -> 'This is my message'
 }('This is my message');
```

by passing it as a callback

```
someFn( param1, param1, function( msg ) {
   console.log( msg );
});
```

Comment: How would the callback work, you set 3 parameters? `someFn(x, y, z)`?

Comment: There are more than 4 ways to call an anonymous function, for example: `(function(msg){ console.log(msg) }).call(null, 'Hello World');`

Comment: hey @tmyie it may be a bit beyond the scope of the question but essentially the function would use the first two params for something and call the callback when it wanted to. It could 1 param or twenty it really doesn't matter, it was just to show you another anonymous functions can be used, give me second and I will set up jsfiddle for you

Comment: @RobM. this is correct however i didn't see the need to go in to call and apply as it seems they wanted it in context of how they are used in a real world experience, not just any way possible

Comment: Fair enough, but they are actually used quite frequently in the real world. Take for instance jQuery's `.each` method: the fact that you can reference the current DOM node using `this` within your anonymous function is due to jquery using `callback.call(DOMNode, DOMNode, index)`

Comment: yeah absolutely but they are really calling it behind the scenes as a parameter to another function, i meant actually written out as an anonymous function and then being called with call, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

You can assign functions defined with this syntax to variables, just like other objects:

```
var myAlert = function(msg) { alert(msg); };
myAlert("hello!");
```

The most common use case for anonymous functions is as a *higher order function* - when you provide a function as an argument to another function. A common example is an AJAX request - you provide a callback function to be executed when the request completes. Using jQuery, you could write:

```
$.get('/someurl', myAlert);
```

jQuery would execute `myAlert` when the resource at `/someurl` responds.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to assigning it to a variable, as [*joews*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20229709/1715579) points out, you can call it immediately like this:

```
(function(msg) { alert(msg); })('hello!');
```

Or you might want to pass it as a parameter to another function, like this:

```
['hello!'].forEach(function(msg) { alert(msg); });
```

Answer (score 0):

By itself, it isn't.  You need to have some sort of a reference to it.

```
function(msg) { alert(msg); }();
// alert will appear

var f = function(msg) { alert(msg); };
f();
// alert will appear

$.ajax({
         url: '/some/ajax/url',
         method:' get'
       })
.done(function(msg) { alert(msg); });
// alert will appear displaying the response data.
```

The idea there is the `done` function takes a parameter and it executes that parameter, like so:

```
function done(callback) {
    ...
    callback(responseData);
}
```

My usage of the jquery ajax api may not be accurate.  I did this quickly to illustrate the point.

This pattern is called a function expression by the way, when you pass an inline function to something or assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

must be assigned to a var

For example

```
var f = function () {};
```

Or assigned to a arg of function

```
Fun(arg1, function (){});
```